# Sri Vidya, Maha Shodashi, Sri Yantra

Tags: sri-vidya

Why there are so many different ways of Puja in sri vidya? why All Gurus started new different Puja, which shashtra one should refer to learn SRI VIDYA. ?

Comment: You should get initiated into Sri Vidya first from a Sampradaya guru and then follow his methods. We are not supposed to learn it by reading Shastras. The knowledge has to come from the Guru. Difference in methods which you might find are possibly due to Samparadya Bheda. There are different schools of Sri Vidya.